# Can't create jagged dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe with 2 columns and 2rows.
I also have a list of 4 numbers.

I want to concatenate this list to the FIRST column of the dataframe, and only the first. So the dataframe will have 6rows in the first column, and 2in the second.

I wrote this code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
numbers = [5, 6, 7, 8]
for i in range(0, 4):
    df1['A'].loc[i + 2] = numbers[i]
print(df1)
```

It prints the original dataframe oddly enough. But when I debug and evaluate the expression `df1['A']` then it does show the new numbers. What's going on here?

It's not just that it's printing the original df, it also writes the original df to csv when I use to_csv method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    df1.loc[0, i] = numbers[i]
print (df1)
   A  B    0    1    2    3
0  1  2  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
1  3  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame([numbers], index=[0])], axis=1)
print (df1)
   A  B    0    1    2    3
0  1  2  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
1  3  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```